# QueryDSL not using Postgres Indexes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, querydsl

I'm using Hibernate and QueryDSL along with PostgreSQL on a Spring application, and face some performance issues with my filtered lists. Using the StringPath class, I'm calling either startsWithIgnoreCase, endsWithIgnoreCase or containsIgnoreCase.
It appears the generated query has the following where clause :

```
WHERE lower(person.firstname) LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'
```

Using the lower, the query is not taking advantage of the Postgres indexes. On a dev Database, queries take up to 1sec instead of 10ms with the ILIKE keyword.

Is there a way to get a Predicate using Postgres' ILIKE, as Ops doesn't seem to provide it?

Thanks

Comment: You can create an index on `lower(firstname)` that should be used by the query (but only if the wildcards are at the end of the comparison value). Another option would be to create a trigram index: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: Thanks, it does answer my initial question, although I find myself struggling with other issues. We're already using trigram indexes, but it appears Postgre is not using the expected index. I'll try to figure out if we can remove the conflicting index (using btree on two columns), otherwise I'm a bit short on this issue.
I also tried using citext data type, but the query analyzer shows that there are no index used, and searches indicates this issue, with lower index as a solution : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-column-with-data-type-citext-not-used/105250#105250

Comment: Please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and then add the missing information to your question. This is impossible to answer without more information (and: it's either Postgres, PostgreSQL or simply pg, but never Postgre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to update this :

We found a way to create the needed Postgres operators by registering a SQL function using ilike, in our custom Hibernate Dialect.

Example with ilike :

```
//Postgres Constants Operators
public class PostgresOperators {
    private static final String NS = PostgresOperators.class.getName();
    public static final Operator<Boolean> ILIKE = new OperatorImpl<>(NS, "ILIKE");
}

//Custom JPQLTemplates
public class PostgresTemplates extends HQLTemplates {

    public static final PostgresTemplates DEFAULT = new PostgresTemplates();

    public PostgresTemplates() {
        super();
        add(PostgresOperators.ILIKE, "my_ilike({0},{1})");
    }
}
```

Specify the JPQLTemplates when using jpaquery

```
new JPAQuery(entityManager, PostgresTemplates.DEFAULT);
```

now it gets tricky, we couldn't use ilike directly, there is an issue with an "ilike" keyword already registered, so we made an ilike function and registered it to a custom spring hibernate Dialect.

Our application.yml specifying :

```
#SEE JPA http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html    
spring.data.jpa:com.example.customDialect.config.database.ExtendedPostgresDialect
```

Then

```
public class ExtendedPostgresDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect {
    public ExtendedPostgresDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("my_ilike", new PostgreSQLIlikeFunction());
    }
}
```

We tried to use the registerKeyword("ilike"), didn't work, we stayed with our function and the following implementation.

```
public class PostgreSQLIlikeFunction implements SQLFunction {

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type columnType, Mapping mapping)
        throws QueryException {
        return new BooleanType();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
        if (args.size() != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The function must be passed 2 arguments");
        }

        String str1 = (String) args.get(0);
        String str2 = (String) args.get(1);

        return str1 + " ilike " + str2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

That's pretty much it, now we can use ILIKE the following way :

```
 BooleanOperation.create(PostgresOperators.ILIKE, expression1, expression2).isTrue()
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got exactly the same issue - `lower(column)` causes wrong pg statistics calculation and request is planned not efficiently, `ilike` solves the problem. I hadn't understood what parts of OP's answer are relevant to solution so reinvented the same approach, but a bit shorter.

1. Introduce new dialect with `my_ilike` function and it's implementation:

   ```
   public class ExtendedPostgresDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect {
       public ExtendedPostgresDialect() {
           super();
           registerFunction("my_ilike", new SQLFunctionTemplate(BooleanType.INSTANCE, "(?1 ilike ?2)"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Specify this dialect to be used by Hibernate (I use Java config):

   ```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "com.example.ExtendedPostgresDialect");
   factory.setJpaProperties(props);
   ```
3. That's it, now you can use it:

   ```
   BooleanTemplate.create("function('my_ilike', {0}, {%1%})", stringPath, value).isTrue();
   ```

Comment: In the new version of QueryDSL, they have replaced BooleanTemplate.create(...) with Expressions.booleanTemplate(....)